# Change Jinja Child Template in response to HTML event

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dom, jinja2

Suppose I have a base template `base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have several possible child templates for the `content` block, say `child1.html`,  `child2.html` etc.

Is it possible to switch between them in response to an HTML event on the page, say using Javascript? (My motivation is to let the user click on buttons on the page to change the page style.)

I am using Jinja2 with Python on Google App Engine.

Apparently it seems that the template is set by server side scripts so this should not be possible, but I was hoping someone must have wanted to do something similar before.

Comment: why not put the child templates in their own `<div>`s, then show/hide them as needed with JS?

Comment: @MattDMo, that sure would work, I was just hoping for a more elegant solution if possible.

Comment: then, I suspect AJAX is your best bet. Also, depending on exactly how you're implementing the style changes, you could do it all with CSS3 and JS manipulation, and only have to request the content from the server once.

Answer (score 2):

You noted properly, that the jinja2 template is rendered server side while JavaScript runs in your browser.

So JavaScript has no direct chance to affect how is the template rendered.

There could be some solutions, e.g.

### Generate both versions of content

Generate them hidden, let your JavaScript show just one of them

### AJAX - pull proper content from JavaScript

JavaScript would detect what is to be inside and using AJAX call would pull what is needed.